# How to change combobox in item template with respect to the data coming from code behind or data source in DataGrid

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio, datagrid

I have a data grid, and data is coming from database, it has combo boxes in status and I want them to be according to their respective values, for example, there is a column of status, it has a combo box: Open and Close, I want it to be changed with respect to the value it has in database table-column, if it has Close written in database table column, combo box should be selected as Close, if it has Open then it should be selected as Open. Please see the image attached.
[image]
Thanks for Help in advance.

Comment: Why not set the comboBox column in that dataGridView to have two permitted values: 'Open' and 'Close'. Query the SQL Database and retreve the results for the partucular record (perhaps based on 'process key' in this case?). Then test the returned string `if (String.Compare(str1, str2, true) == 0) {// Select the appropriate comboBoxItem}`...

Comment: Best practice is to use lable or BoundField to show data in grid view rather than using combobox or listbox.

Comment: @Chirag Fanse: What kind of advice are you giving here? That is not best practice. Obviously, OP needs to be able to change the status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're using a template column, you can do this:

```
<asp:TemplateColumn>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Eval("DropDownValueColumn") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn>
```

If you want to set the SelectedValue in the `ItemDataBound` event, you can do it like this:

```
protected void DataGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddl = e.Item.FindControl("DropDownList1") as DropDownList;
    if (ddl != null)
    {
        ddl.SelectedValue = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "DropDownColumnValue").ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

First of all save your data source in viewstate. If datasource is datatable then do like this.

```
protected void gridview1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {

            DropDownList ddlList = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("Name_of_DPList");
            int i=e.Row.RowIndex;
            DataTable dtTable = (DataTable)ViewState["dtPurchaseOrder"];
            string str = dtTable.Rows[i]["Name_Of_column"].ToString();//Name of the column in data source that stores the status.
            ddlList.items.FindByText(str).Selected=true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: -1 You should NEVER store a datasource in ViewState. If that DataTable has a lot of records the ViewState will be huge, which will bring the page to its knees. That's horrible advice.

Comment: That's not even necessary in this case. You already have access to the data through `e.Item.DataItem`.